# REST API application does not work on domain

Tags: javascript, java, rest, netbeans, localhost

I moved my REST API web app to registered domain. On localhost is working as intended, however when deploying to server I get following error

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

I use JS to access REST API.

Localhost http://localhost:8080/EB-Software/apii/user-form/retrieve worked perfectly, whereas http://eb-software.uk/EB-Software/apii/user-form/retrieve leads to error above.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Update the URL like this, just remove `EB-Software`

```
http://eb-software.uk/apii/user-form/retrieve
```

Comment: Please answer with explanation.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500

Comment: Does this Spring app deployed with tomcat?

Comment: When I used http://eb-software/apii/user-form/retrieve i get 500 error, and when http://apii/user-form/retrieve i get Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED , please help

Comment: @sc0der  it is rest api jersey, no spring, deployed in tomcat, correct

Comment: Let me check that

Comment: @Bartosz what is the name of the service and URL to get suppliers?

Comment: apii/user-form/retrieve hosted on http://eb-software.uk/

Comment: Then in JS file type the url like this:  for example `$.getJSON("/apii/user-form/retrieve", function(data)` , If didn't work try this `$.getJSON("apii/user-form/retrieve", function(data)`

Comment: Dear, unfortunately retrieve:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500